# 2048 game will not open (Ubuntu 14.04 in VMware Player)

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, lts

I've found this site : http://www.unixmen.com/install-2048-game-ubuntu/
I downloaded the open-source puzzler @ http://sourceforge.net/projects/linuxfreedomfor/files/ubuntu/2048_1_all.deb & installed it via terminal : sudo dpkg -i 2048_1_all.deb
When I launch the 2048 game from the Unity Dash it will not open.

Comment: Can you try running it from a terminal?

Comment: Good question.  When I type "2048" (without "") I get "command not found".  How can I find the right name of the command?

Comment: You can try pressing Tab to autocomplete the command, or maybe `ls /usr/bin | grep 2048`

Comment: Pressing Tab to autocomplete the command does not work here.  "ls /usr/bin | grep 2048"  does not give a result.

Comment: Try `dpkg-query -c 2048_1_all.deb` to see what files the package installs.

Comment: Your dpkg command gives an error.  When I try "dpkg -L 2048" it gives a lot of files.  2048 doesn't use an exe but an html-file (/usr/share/2048/index.html).

Comment: So can you do `xdg-open /usr/share/2048/index.html`?

Comment: With "xdg-open /usr/share/2048/index.html" I can open the 2048 game.  How can I assign "xdg-open /usr/share/2048/index.html" to the 2048 game icon in the Unity Dash?  And how do you put your syntax with a grey background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it won't open after installing the program sounds like a bug with the program, you would have to report that to the developer.

The `dpkg -L 2048` command will show what files are installed for the program. It shows that `/usr/share/2048/index.html` is installed, and this is the main file for the program. You can open this with the default browser using `xdg-open`:

```
xdg-open /usr/share/2048/index.html
```

You could create your own launcher for the game from one of the following guides:

[How can I edit/create new launcher items in Unity by hand?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13758/how-can-i-edit-create-new-launcher-items-in-unity-by-hand/68023)

[How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-deskt)

Short code snippets use backticks `, probably upper left corner of your keyboard. For more about formatting, see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I think the real answer should be the `xdg-open /usr/share/2048/index.html` part. All the other bits are dupes, really.

Comment: Ok, problem solved.  Thank you very much for your help Nattgew.

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me after a fresh install- but in 'alacarte'(main menu icon) -> games 2048 -> properties I substituted in 'command'  xdg-open /opt/2048/data/index.html - now game opens in a new tab in chromium as before.